# create the for loop in the variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some help with my code. I'm creating a variable with a for loop to allow me to get the list of elements.

When I try this:

```
channels = map(str, channels)
channels = str(channels)
channel = [channels for channel in channels]
print channel
```

I will get the long list of elements like this:

```
13:54:18 T:4308  NOTICE: ["['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']", "['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']"]
```

Here is what the output is when I use `print channels`

```
14:01:19 T:1616  NOTICE: ['101 BBC One S East ', '102 BBC Two ', '103 ITV ', '104 Channel 4 ', '105 Channel 5 ', '106 Sky One ', '107 Sky Living ']
```

Here is the full code:

```
CHANNELS_PER_PAGE = 7
#get the channels list
cur.execute('SELECT channel FROM programs WHERE channel GROUP BY channel')
channelList = list()
for index in range(0, CHANNELS_PER_PAGE):
    channel = channelList[index]
    channel_index = index

    channels.append(channel)
channels = map(str, channels)
channels = str(channels)
channel = [channels for channel in channels]
print channel
```

I want to use the variable where it have the for loop inside the variable.

Can you please tell me how I can print each of the element from the list without repeating when creating the for loop in the variable?

Comment: Doesn't that crash at `channel = channelList[index]`? It should also crash at `channels.append(channel)`. And `CHANNELS_PER_PAGE`, for that matter, unless this isn't actually the full code.

Comment: @ TigerhawkT3: No it doesn't crash, it will work fine without it. Sorry I have forgot to include the `CHANNELS_PER_PAGE`. Please see my update code

Comment: I don't see how. You create `channelList` as an empty `list`, then try to create a `range` object by passing it an undefined variable `CHANNELS_PER_PAGE`. Then you try to index the empty `channelList` (with an ordinary integer instead of a slice). Then you `append` to an undefined variable `channels`. I stopped there.

Comment: @TigerhawklT3 do you know how I can output the list of element without repeating something similar like this `channel = [channels for channel in channels]`?

Comment: At this point, I don't even know what `channel` and `channels` _are_. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as this is not complete, minimal, or verifiable.

Comment: @TigerhawklT3: the `channels` is the variable that I pulled the data from the database and I create `channel` as the new variable where I want to use it with for loop inside that variable to get the list of elements to print each of them. How I can use the for loop in the `channel` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Answer

This code is *completely* wrong:

```
channels = map(str, channels)
channels = str(channels)
channel = [channels for channel in channels]
print channel
```

Instead of that, to print each channel, you would do this:

```
for channel in channels:
    print channel
```

### Details

#### Terminology

There is no such thing as *"for loop inside the variable"*. What you have is a variable which has a value. The value can be an object of any type, e.g. a string or a list.

#### Your Code

Let's go through your code, line by line...

The first line converts each member of `channels` into a string:

```
channels = map(str, channels)
```

For example, if you had integers in the list (`[1, 2, 3]`), this would convert them to strings (`['1', '2', '3']`).

The next line converts the whole `channels` object into one string:

```
channels = str(channels)
```

So, the *1,2,3* example would now become `"['1', '2', '3']"`.

The next line is a list comprehension. it goes through all elements of `channels` (`for channel in channels`) and for each of them, adds `channels` to the list. Then, it stores everything into variable named `channel`:

```
channel = [channels for channel in channels]
```

I have no idea what the intention was. Anyway, the end result is comparable to what you would get with the following code:

```
channel = []
for character in channels:
    # Goes through all 15 characters of "['1', '2', '3']"
    # Ignores the character, appends the whole `characters` string to the list
    channel.append(channels)
```

Note that on the previous line `channels` was converted to a string, so iterating through `channels` actually iterates through characters.

So, after that line, for the *1,2,3* input, `channel` would be 15 times `"['1', '2', '3']"` string.

#### A Simple Guideline

If you don't know what a line of code does, try printing the result. That is simple and effective. For example:

```
print channels
channels = map(str, channels)
print channels
channels = str(channels)
print channels
channel = [channels for channel in channels]
print channel
```

Then see if what you got is what you wanted for each of the lines.

Comment: thank you very much for your advice, I did not realised that I used the wrong code so I have made a mistake. Lesson learned! :)